# WPF Listview sort works only one time, and then nothing happen

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listview

I have a ListView in a WPF window, that I am trying to sort by clicking on the columns.
To learn how to do this, I followed this link: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-how-to-column-sorting/

I have created the method GridViewColumnHeader_Cick as follow:

```
private void GridViewColumnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewColumnHeader column = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader);
    string sortBy = column.Tag.ToString();
    searchResultListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    searchResultListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortBy, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

It works the first time I click on a column header, but if I click on another column header after, nothing happen. I tried to execute it step-by-step, but I could not find anything that would cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you didn't copy-paste columns with the same tag in xaml.

Comment: No, they were all different from each other. But my tags had spaces that I just removed. I don't know if it was the real cause, but it works perfectly fine now. Thank you for your help

Comment: It could be a cause. Tag is passed to constructor of SortDescriptor as a param. This param has a "propertyName" meaning and i'm not sure if propertyName could contain space character.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the sort direction. You are hard-coding ascending sort into the sort description.